# Como dar update em uma linha(row) no dataTable? (Primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eai pessoal? Por favor, algum ninja javeiro pode me ajudar com esse caso? 
Tenho uma dataTable e preciso saber como dar um update em uma unica row após algum evento, como por exemplo um clique em um commandButton.

Eu estudei um pouco sobre o 'omnifaces' antes que alguém comente sobre ele aqui hehe, mas infelizmente não consegui fazer funcionar como nos exemplos que eles apresentam, muito pelo contrario, esse da um refresh na minha página inteira :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver o problema! Não teve jeito, foi necessário usar a biblioteca do *omnifaces* (link para quem quiser ver mais http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax).

Antes com o *omnifaces* ele dava um *refresh* em minha página inteira, aparentemente resolvi esse problema incluindo Ids em todos os meus componentes da dataTable e utilizando apenas componentes do primefaces (antes eu tinha alguns componentes JSF no meio). Além disso é claro, me baseei nos códigos de exemplo da biblioteca.

Comment: obrigado, estava com o mesmo problema.
Funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei em dúvida sobre esse update. É update no banco? Ou apenas uma atualização de tela?

Se for atualização de tela, acredito atributo **update** resolva seu problema.

*ps.: não falei mais sobre o atributo, pois não sei se é isso que você procura.*

Comment: Opa Luke, desculpe a escassez de informações hehe. Quando me referi ao update, é o update na tela mesmo, mais especificamente da row que selecionei, preciso só disparar um evento que de um refresh nessa linha em especifico. Consigo dar um update no dataTable inteiro após esse evento, mas isso causa uma lentidão danada e ao meu ver desnecesária, visto que só quero dar o refresh em uma linha! Obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: esqueci de menciona-lo no comentário anterior